# How Implement TSP in Self Organizing-Maps

Tags: algorithm, som

I wanna ask about implement TSP in Self Organizing Maps (SOM). How the SOM algorithm/working for get result of path for TSP?

Answer (score 1):

The travelling Salesman Problem (TSP) is an optimization problem. There are many algorithms that attempt to solve the TSP including metaheuritics like Genetic Algorithms. On the other Hand Self Organizing Maps is a type of neural networks originally designed for data clustering and visualziation, as well as dimnensionality reduction. In other words, the original SOM algorithm has been created to tackle a different family of problems than the TSP. However, it is possible to modify the original SOM method to solve the TSP. A Journal article titled "An new self-organizing maps strategy for solving the traveling salesman problem" addresses this interesting approach, and can be found in the following URL

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960077905007083